# How to read a config file from a command line using perl (automation)

Tags: perl, automation, automated-tests

I am new to Perl and need help with this.

I want to read a config file and see if the first 10 lines of the file contents starts with `#` and have or not have some particular string to do some automation in Perl.

I was able to open the file using:

```
 $obj->cmd("path");
 $a = ->obj(cat "/path/.config");
```

I don't know if we can save this to variable or is there any way I can copy it to the text file and search it.

Also how do I edit this file like adding or removing file content.

Thank you

Comment: Can anyone please answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a file for reading use:

```
open(my $fh, "<", "/path/.config") or die "Can't open < .config: $!";
```

To open a file for writing

```
open(my $fh, ">", "/path/.config") or die "Can't open > .config: $!";
```

the content of the file is then assigned to `$fh`

Comment: Any libraries to be used? @Gerhard Barnard

Comment: no, that is standard perl [3 handle](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) file open functions.

Comment: I have the impression this is an answer to a different question. The OP said _“I want to read a config file and see if the first 10 lines of the file contents starts with # and have or not have some particular string to do some automation in Perl.”_ And the title says _“from the command line”_. I rather thought of something more like `perl -ne 'print if (…)' < /path/.config`. But given that this answer is the accepted one, `open(my $fh,'<','filename');` seems to solve all those aforementioned problems.

Comment: @PerlDuck Yeah though it was not all the answer, I thought I can parse the file once I read it or save it. but got stuck again while parsing. I would be glad if you can give me some inputs for the approach.

Comment: @PerlDuck Also can you tell what does -ne do here?

Comment: @joey `-e` means "execute the Perl code given at the command line" (and not a script), `-n` means "execute that code for every single line of the input, but don't automatically print the line". See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches for details. /// But I gave only an example, not actual code. You asked for a command line solution, and they _typically_ involve the `-n -e` switches.